# How to hide a button and get it to take up its space while its hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code where I am trying to have two buttons Reset form and Save next to each other. When user lands on page I want Save button to be hidden. When he goes through the forms then this button should appear. While the Save button is hidden I want Save button to still take up its space so buttons don't move around when the Save button appears at the end of the forms. 
How do I get the Save button to hide and still take up the space when its hidden in same row next to Reset Form button ?

```
<div class="commandButtons">       
    <span class="commandButtonsRight">
        <button class="k-button k-button-icontext"  hidden ="true" data-bind="click: save">
            <span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save
        </button>
        <button class="k-button k-button-icontext" data-bind="click: cancel">
            <span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>Reset Form
        </button>
    </span>
```

Comment: I'd have a disabled version that when it becomes time to make it clickable you swap the disabled version for the enabled version. This both tells the user where the save button is and that there's not yet anything to save.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.save {
  visibility:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="commandButtons">       
    <span class="commandButtonsRight">
        <button class="k-button k-button-icontext save" data-bind="click: save">
            <span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save
        </button>
        <button class="k-button k-button-icontext" data-bind="click: cancel">
            <span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>Reset Form
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `opacity` to `0`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/qjwf4ukc/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
#hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="commandButtonsRight">
        <button id="hide" class="k-button k-button-icontext" data-bind="click: save">
            <span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save
</button>
<button class="k-button k-button-icontext" data-bind="click: cancel">
  <span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>Reset Form
</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by setting its visibility to hidden:

```
.commandButtons {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

If it should still be clickable then you can set its opacity to zero:

```
.commandButtons {
     opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to maintain div space:

CSS

```
.class {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

to not maintain div space:

CSS

```
.class {
   display:none;
}
```